# Avoiding lifetime parameters in rust for a struct?

Tags: rust

How would I go about avoiding the lifetime parameter of an already existing struct in rust? I want to use it in a wasm project, and to be able to return it to javascript I can not use lifetimes.

The following does not work syntactically, but logically I don't see any reason for it not to. A.inner will never outlive A.buf, since they are in the same struct. I can not, however, find any way to express this in rust.

```
struct AInner<'a> {
    parsed_data: u32,
    rest: &'a [u8],
}

struct A {
    buf: Vec<u8>,
    inner: AInner<????> // AInner.rest is referencing A.buf
}
```

Comment: Sorry, a small typo. Edited the question. A is the owner of the vec at A.buf and AInner is referencing the A.buf.

Comment: There are crates for this as well: https://crates.io/crates/ouroboros

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`Rc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Rc.html) and share the pointer:

```rust
use std::rc::Rc;

struct AInner {
    parsed_data: u32,
    rest: Rc<Vec<u8>>,
}

struct A {
    buf: Rc<Vec<u8>>,
    inner: AInner
}

impl A {
    pub fn new(v: Vec<u8>, parsed_data: u32) -> Self {
        let buf = Rc::new(v);
        A {
            buf: buf.clone(),
            inner: AInner {
                rest: buf,
                parsed_data
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8c768bfe75f13233b8d947a02d09d69e)

Comment: I guess this could work for a struct I have control over.... However, I would like to do something like this without changing AInner. Would that be possible?

Comment: @Qoutroy, not afaik. Why cant you use lifetimes though? I have no real experience with wasm.

Comment: Well, I'd like to pass a Vec<u8> from javascript to rust in order to make a new AInner. Since javascript has no control over lifetimes, I have to pass the ovnership of that Vec, and that's why I can't just use AInner. And I don't want to change AInner, since it is used both in rust, and soon on the web.

Comment: `Rc<Vec<u8>>` should probably be replaced by `Rc<[u8]>`, to avoid double indirection.